# Change the background of fa icon on hover

Tags: html, css

I want to achieve the background changing animation while hovering like this [codepen](https://codepen.io/chrisdothtml/pen/azPYqq).
I tried converting the stylus into css but still I cannot make it work. I also tried using the before and after pseudo elements but I still cannot get the results. I changed the background to a gradient and tried to change background position to achieve this but failed in this as well.
Sorry I am a newbie to web development.

```css
.social-buttons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 20px;
}

.social-buttons ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.social-buttons ul li {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.social-buttons ul li .fa {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 25px;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
}

.fa-instagram {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.fa-pinterest {
  color: red;
}

.fa-facebook {
  color: blue;
}

.fa-youtube {
  color: red;
}

.social-buttons ul li:hover .fa {
  font-size: 30px;
  color: black;
}

.social-buttons ul li:hover .fa-instagram {
  color: black;
  background: none;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: unset;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fc692f1356.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="social-buttons">
  <ul>
    <a href="#">
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
      </li>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
      <li>
        <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>
      </li>
    </a>
  </ul>
```

Comment: are you talking about the hover animation?

Comment: Yes, I want to achieve the background changing animation while hovering.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Where is your background? You say you tried pseudo elements and background gradient, but that's not in your CSS.

Comment: I am sorry I deleted those as they were not working. As I m new I thought my approach was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the way they're showing in that example I might recommend an alternate method in this case and utilize `transform` with a `keyframe` animation instead of property `transition` so you get a little perk from the GPU.

The pseudo element is a good way and the `cubic-bezier` adds the bouncy effect, except I didn't take the one from your example because it felt like a jerky animation. However this should get you closer to your goal. Also changed your `li` to the anchors with `display: list-item` and a couple other things to steer towards some WCAG. Cheers.

```css
.social-buttons {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 20px;
}

.social-buttons ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.social-buttons ul a {
  display: list-item;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

@keyframes topRight {
  to { transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(0,0) };
}

.social-buttons ul a:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 150px;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #0f0;
  transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-100px, -100px);
}

.social-buttons ul a:hover:before {
  animation: topRight .5s cubic-bezier(.22,.68,0,1.71) forwards;
}

.social-buttons ul a .fa {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  font-size: 25px;
  transition: all 0.1s ease-in;
}

.fa-instagram {
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 30% 107%, #fdf497 0%, #fdf497 5%, #fd5949 45%, #d6249f 60%, #285AEB 90%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.fa-pinterest {
  color: red;
}

.fa-facebook {
  color: blue;
}

.fa-youtube {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/fc692f1356.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="social-buttons">
  <ul>
    <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-pinterest"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>
    </a>
  </ul>
```

Comment: I thought people are gonna get angry at me after seeing my code. Thanks for helping me and my code better.

Comment: @yashthe no worries, we've all been there. Just show effort and pay it forward when you get a chance. If your question is answered mark it as such so future viewers know. Welcome to SO ;)

Comment: why are my last two hover animations not working (Changing the icon colour to black and increasing the font size of the icon)

Comment: @yashthe There was orphan css I left from your example at the bottom still applying to `li` so I'm guessing you pasted the css in somewhere and it's still finding its selector. I edited the answer to remove it though, give it another try.

Comment: Can you help ? I m having an issue . @Chris

Comment: @yashthe is it the same question or a new one?

Comment: The centering we are using above                                                                              top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);                                                                                                     Is not working on iPad safari and it works fine on everything else.

Comment: @yashthe add `-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%)` to account for Safari's BS way of handling certain attributes by requiring a [vendor specific prefix](http://shouldiprefix.com/) of `-webkit-` and you're good. Cheers!

Comment: I added the above but it still isnt working.

Comment: @yashthe I assume you're just missing the vendor prefix in the right places and having both like the `transform` and `-webkit-transform` or perhaps a type on the `-webkit-` portion because that's pretty much definitely your culprit. Could always also change the semantics to not use the centering `transform` at all if you want but I don't own any apple products to reproduce the issue, but you could update your question with your current attempt if you want and I can take a peek. There's lots of alternate ways to accomplish the same effect.

Comment: @yashthe sorry dude but that link is broken

Comment: If you have some time Please can you visit a website I m making artworx.epizy.com               I have completed only the home page and contact me page and correct my mistakes

Comment: @yashthe silly question, but did you clear your cache or visit the same url from an incognito window before re-trying? I can only test in an emulator for safari but looks (and would be expected to be after adding the prefixes) to act as expected. As for doing a review of your website well sorry friend but that's a bit more free time than I have at the moment.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯